# Substring (...,...,CHARINDEX(....)-0.5) function

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, substring, charindex

I have this string in a column called `Parent_ID`. Example of the strings that exist there:

```
RBIA-3340-CU-XM-01-D/RBIA-3340-01-4-D-34080-11441A1-2TC-001/B1
```

what I want is to get:

```
RBIA-3340-CU-XM-01-D/RBIA-3340-01-4-D-34080-11441A1-2TC-001
```

without `/B1`

When I wrote this code:

```
SELECT Substring([parent_id], 1,
                 CHARINDEX('/B',parent_id,25)-1)
FROM [c3d_aug].[dbo].[atta_properties]
```

I got this error:

> "Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 Invalid length parameter passed to
>   the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

After testing I accidentally changed `-1` to `-0.5` it worked fine.

```
SELECT Substring([parent_id],1,
                 CHARINDEX('/B',parent_id,25)-0.5)
FROM [c3d_aug].[dbo].[atta_properties]
```

Can someone explain why ?! please, note that main string given above does not contain any spaces.

Comment: Nope it is CHARINDEX is returning 60 in your example

Comment: declare @Parentid varchar(max) = 'RBIA-3340-CU-XM-01-D/RBIA-3340-01-4-D-34080-11441A1-2TC-001/B1'

select charindex('/B', @parentid)  -- Returns 60
select substring(@parentid,1,  charindex('/B', @parentid) - 1)

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend that you use `-0.5`.  It probably works because negative numbers are "truncated" toward zero for negative numbers when floats are converted back to integers (as the function requires).

I would instead suggest:

```
SElECT LEFT([parent_id],
            CHARINDEX('/B', parent_id + '/B', 25) - 1
           )
FROM [c3d_aug].[dbo].[atta_properties];
```

By adding the pattern at the end of the string, you don't have to worry about a return of `0` from `CHARINDEX()`.

`LEFT()` is just more convenient for this than `SUBSTRING()`.

Comment: sorry for asking again , but why we would get a 0 from a charindex function ?

Comment: the function is supposed to give the location of a certain character ?, 
I am just new to SQL , sorry for asking a lot 

and thank you for your reply

Comment: @AutomationENG . . . The function returns `0` when the string is not found.